# How to read in OTHER file with read.csv in R, if first file is not found?

Tags: r, read.csv

I am using R to read in a file, therefore I use read.csv. The files come from a dataset and are all tagged by a date. However, some dates are missing. For date X, I want to read in a file "X". Because some files are missing, R gives me `"Error in a file(file, "rt")` : cannot open the connection". Instead, I want R to automatically read in file `"X-1" if "X"` is nonexistent `(or "X-2" if "X-1" is also nonexistent etcetera)`. Thus, I am looking for some kind of "IFERROR" statement to get around this. I could not find this kind of statement, does anyone know how to detect a "rt" and act on it? Regards, Margot

Comment: Can you shows us a sample of your dataset that you're trying to read in ?

Comment: Could you make a folder called "data" in your working directory where you put all of these `csvs`?  Then you could say `l = lapply(paste0("data/", dir("data")), read.csv)` to read in all the `csvs` in the folder, and store them in a list.

Comment: You could use `file.exists` before you try to load it, like
`if(file.exists('X'){
  df <- read.csv('X')
} else if (file.exists('X-1')){
...
}`

Comment: Can't you read contents of a folder using `list.files` and skip all the error checking?

Comment: Thanks, using file.exists works!